# Fullpage.js and mobile devices: how to trigger slide change before?

Tags: fullpage.js

I developed a website with fullpage.js and everything seems to work ok 
but on mobile it seems that it gets triggered the slide change event when the bottom or top of next slide hits the center of the viewport.

How can I trigger this action earlier like at 1/3 from bottom or top of the viewport?

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    licenseKey: '*****',
    css3: true,
    scrollingSpeed: 1100,
    scrollBar: false,
    scrollOverflow: true,
    anchors:['s00','s01','s02','s03','s04','s05'],
    animateAnchor: true,
    responsiveWidth: 992
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately fullpage.js doesn't provide such option at the moment. 
You can meanwhile trigger the change by using any scrolling animation library such as scrollreveal https://scrollrevealjs.org/ when in responsive mode.

Comment: Ok, thank. Since you are the developer of the script I guess I can't get a better answer. Wouldn't be better if you write as an answer? How can I close the question? Thanks